# Run first Angular 2 app

Tags: angular

I just followed some instruction on how to run the Angular 2 app, but I'm getting this response. I'm not sure what's going on. Can somebody please help me to understand if something is broken or not because some of the things seems not to be installed here.

[image]

Comment: all of those are warnings and not errors, and as you can see few modules are installed. run the app using `npm start`

Comment: AngularJS != Angular 2/4, and the quick start is not for AngularJS (tag removed).

Comment: npm start won't work, it responds " Cannot GET / "

Comment: `Cannot GET /` seems to be an error in code and not with `npm command`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this are some warning because of deprecated packages in this repository. everything is installed well still. when you want to build new angular application i would recommend to use angular CLI. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do this instead cloning repo and installing dependencies.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Once angular-cli installed

```
cd path/to/your/dev/dir
ng new my-app
```

now you'll get latest angular code base. within dir **my-app**